# image scaling with rotation in android like photoshop

Tags: android, android-layout

how to implement image rotation and image scaling on android imageview means suppose we have a image we want to image large and small by stretch from image corner like photoshop how to implement this feature

Comment: Here is something i found >http://mobisocial.stanford.edu/news/2011/08/rotating-images-in-android/ >http://www.anddev.org/resize_and_rotate_image_-_example-t621.html >http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Images-In-Android/3/ Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

It may help you :

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/07/skew-bitmap-image-using-matrix.html

[image]

Comment: http://goo-android.blogspot.in/2010/07/rotate-bitmap-image-using-matrix.html but here BG and text both are in black color :) so select the text to read. :)